# Can't connect to LAN server on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my brother have been tying to step up a LAN to play minecraft. I have a mac running Mac OS X and he is using  a pc running window's 7. We have tried with him creating the LAN world and when I try to automatically it gives a message that it has 'time out' and when I do Direct connect it fails and gives a message 'connection refused'. When I host the game and he does direct connected it gives the same message. We are both running the same version. Anyone have any ideas ???

Comment: Do you have Mojang accounts, or are you trying to use Offline Mode?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie why do these accounts get insta-deleted like this?

Comment: @Ender Huh, well that will make this hard to clarify. Maybe it's a rage-quit reaction when we can't mind read?